# How to convert a spatialpolygon to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and add a column to the attribute table

Tags: r, cartography

```
coast<-readShapeSpatial("coastline.shp")
landc<-readShapeSpatial("landcover.shp")
ro<-readShapeSpatial("roads.shp")
bc<-gBuffer(ro,width=100)
landc$ratings=1
landc$ratings[landc$LANDUSE_ID==4]=0
```

Above, I take any category that has 4 and in the new column put it as 0.

At this point, I want the column named `ratings` as well for the `bc`, where it will take 0 if it is inside the buffer and 1 if it is outside. The problem is that the `bc` is `SpatialPolygons` and it doesn't contain the attribute table.

Obviously to add a column to a `SpatialPolygon` object you have to convert it to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, but I don't know how.

I tried this:

```
buf_df<-as.data.frame(bc)
s_po<-SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(bc,buf_df)
s_po$ratings=0
```

but this error pops up:

```
row.names of data and Polygons IDs do not match
```

Comment: Well, if you read the help for gBuffer you would know that if byid=TRUE the result is a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

Answer (score 15):

What do the "coast", "ro" and "bc" objects have to do with your problem? The issue may lie in that you are using "readShapeSpatial". Have you tried readOGR in rgdal? If you are reading a polygon shapefile, readOGR will result in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object.

If you in fact, do have a SpatialPolygons object and want to coerce into  SpatialPolygonsDataFrame the specified dataframe will need to have its rownames match the polygon ID's in the polygons slot. Here is a quick example.

```
library(sp)

# create some SpatialPolygons with ID's "2" and "3"
( p <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))), "2"),
     Polygons(list(Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))), "3"))) )
class(p)    

# Create a dataframe and display default rownames
( p.df <- data.frame( ID=1:length(p)) ) 
rownames(p.df)

# Try to coerce to SpatialPolygonsDataFrame (will throw error)
p <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p, p.df) 

# Extract polygon ID's
( pid <- sapply(slot(p, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID")) )

# Create dataframe with correct rownames
( p.df <- data.frame( ID=1:length(p), row.names = pid) )    

# Try coersion again and check class
 p <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p, p.df)
 class(p) 

# Now we can add a column
p@data$ratings <- 1:2 

# Or modify an existing one
p[p$ID < 2 ,] <- 5
```

Comment: i showed the rest of the code like the "coast","ro" and "bc" to help you get the idea of what i am trying to do in general. i need to get a more to the point answer of what i'm asking and it would be wise to use my own variables in order to be more understandable.Plus, what is the deal with the readOGR and the readShapeSpatial? The "bc" contains the roads buffer which is the spatialpolygons object that i need  to add the new column to, thus i have to convert it to a spatialPolygonsDataFrame first.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
#Code taken from the question:
s_po <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(bc, buf_df, match.ID = F)
```

`match.ID` avoids the requirement of rownames for match polygons ID

Comment: Don't be contrary, it is not appreciated! The reason "complicated" answers were provided is because in 2015, when the question was addressed, the match.ID argument was not available in the coersion method.

Answer (score 7):

It is  quite simple:

```
library("rgdal")
polygons <- readOGR('path_to/file.shp',
                      layer = 'file')
class(polygons)
>[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
>attr(,"package")
>[1] "sp"

poly_df <- as.data.frame(polygons)
# do some staff with "poly_df" that doesn't support SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
# then convert it to SPDF back again
s_poly <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polygons, poly_df)
# add new column to SPDF:
s_poly$new_column <- "some data"
```

When the Error: "row.names of data and Polygons IDs do not match" arise [this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/davis-rug/BmchhejJm4M) seems to be helpful: rename IDs of the dataframe to match IDs of the polygons:

```
newdata <- data.frame(whatever you want in here)
row.names(newdata) <- (however the new polygons are labeled)
polygons <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(polygons, newdata)
```

Comment: Not sure on a couple steps here. This coercion is dubious: as.data.frame(polygons). You example is coercing the object into the same class. Additionally, in a real example you would throw an error because the rownames of the dataframe would not match the ID in the polygon slot(s). You need to pull the polygon ID's and assign them to the rownames before coercion.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, this is a copy-paste from the working code. No errors, everything is working. Just read some documentation on how `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` is created.

Comment: But, since you use readOGR in your example, you are starting with a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and the dataframe you subset already has the correct rownames because you pulled it from the original sp object. It is a strawman example.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans, I edited my answer to clarify the meaning.

Comment: see my last edit in the main post and tell me what i did wrong  cause i think i made it according to your comment but it gives error. Use my own variables to make it more comprehensable. Thanks

Comment: @gsa, firstly what is the class of `bc`, form which package it comes from? I just can't reproduce your error for now. Though I added a workaround I found for the error you get.

Comment: The "bc" is class "SpatialPolygons" from the "sp" package. it contains the buffer of the roads and i want to add into it a column called "ratings" with all the values being zero. Just like i did with the "landc" in main post."landc" is SpatialPolygonsDataFrame,"bc" has to be too i suppose, in order to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 1):

I find the following solution generally works.

First, create an empty dataframe with ID as field:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=character(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE )
```

Then get the IDs of spatial polygon `bc`:

```
for (i in bc@polygons ) { df <- rbind(df, data.frame(ID=i@ID, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))  }
# and set rowname=ID
row.names(df) <- df$ID
```

Then use df as the second argument to the spatial dataframe conversion function:

```
spatial_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(bc, df)
```

As `df` and `spatial_df` are dataframe objects, columns can be easily added

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution from Roger B. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-December/085175.html

```
yourDF <- as.data.frame(yourPolygon)
```

set rowname=ID from polygon

```
row.names(yourDF) <- sapply(slot(yourPolygon, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
```

Then creates back your Spatial Data Frame with:

```
yourNewPolygon<- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(yourPolygon, yourDF)
```

Test any operation on it like

```
yourNewPolygon<- elide(yourNewPolygon, rotate=-50)
```